# JS: focus on text input after option select in mobile safari

Tags: javascript

i'm using the below code to focus on the text input element after selecting an option from the dropdown menu, it works fine on Chrome for Windows, but Mobile Safari seems to trigger a blur event eventhough the next input is focused:

```html
<select id="demo_1" onchange="if (this.value !== '') document.getElementById('demo_2').focus();">
  <option value="">Select an option</option>
  <option value="Firefox">Firefox</option>
  <option value="Chrome">Chrome</option>
  <option value="Edge">Edge</option>
</select>
<div>i don't like saFari</div>
<input type="text" id="demo_2" />
```

How do i prevent blur when the text input is focused?

P.S: Please note that "focus()" doesn't work correctly with "setTimeout()" in safari, it focuses without popping-up the keyboard.